# What's the preferred directory structure of a non-Rails project with RSpec?

Tags: ruby, testing, rspec, rspec2

I'm new with rspec and I want to use rspec to test my non-Rails project. What I can find on the web are almost all about Rails projects testing with rspec so I need some help on organizing the project structure. Like below, I have an empty directory `my_first_project` and I've executed `rspec --init` in this directory. My question is, where should I put my project code? Directly in `my_first_project` or under `my_first_project\lib` or some other places?

```
MacBook-Pro:my_first_project yi$ rspec --init
  create   .rspec
  create   spec/spec_helper.rb
MacBook-Pro:my_first_project yi$ ls -latrh
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  4 yi staff   136B Jul 14 11:42 ..
drwxr-xr-x  3 yi staff   102B Jul 14 11:42 spec
-rw-r--r--  1 yi staff    41B Jul 14 11:42 .rspec
drwxr-xr-x  4 yi staff   136B Jul 14 11:42 .
MacBook-Pro:my_first_project yi$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build your project [like a `gem`](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/), as that's where you'll probably end up.

Your code goes in the `lib` directory.

```
my_first_project/
├── bin/
│   └── runme.rb
├── lib/
│   ├── my_first_project/
│   │   ├── user.rb
│   │   ├── widget.rb
│   │   └── ...
│   └── my_first_project.rb
├── spec/
│    └── spec_helper.rb
├── .rspec
└── my_first_project.gemspec
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put it either place. Just make sure to require it correctly in the spec_helper file.

If the project file is in the main directory, put in the spec_helper: `require_relative '../project_file.rb'`

Or, if it's in a lib folder, put: `require_relative '../lib/project_file.rb'`

Hope that helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Typically initializing rspec adds .rspec and spec/spec_helper. Because of this it is standard to include a spec directory in the project root directory, and add the spec files into the directory along with a spec_helper file (if they don't already exist). Keeping them in the directory allows you to have files for testing different structures. These can include routing, models, controllers, etc.